# Why are sub-directories not found

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have been looking at other answers here on stackoverflow and elsewhere, to no avail.

I am running a virtual-host localhost and the homepage of the site is showing up fine, but if I go to any subdirectory/subpage I see this error:

> The requested URL /downloads/ was not found on this server

In sum, **mydomain.com** works, but **mydomain.com/downloads/** does not work.

Usually I have fixed this issue with other domains on my localhost by altering `.htaccess`. Here is my current setup:

**Apache2.conf**

```bash
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**mydomain.com.lc.conf** in **sites-available**

```bash
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mydomain.com.lc
        ServerAlias www.mydomain.com.lc
        ServerAdmin myemail@mydomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com.lc/com_mydomain/
        SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV local
        <Directory /var/www/html/mydomain.com.lc/com_mydomain >
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/var/www/html/mydomain.com.lc/com_mydomain/*>
        Allow from all
        Deny from none
        Order deny,allow
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**000-default.conf**

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**etc/hosts**

```bash
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com.lc
```

**.htaccess**

```bash
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

I've tried using no `.htaccess` as well.

Comment: There is a duplicate `/var/www` in `/var/www/var/www/html/mydomain.com.lc/com_mydomain/*`. Not sure if that is causing the issue, though.

Comment: @Jan Papenbrock: Thanks for catching that... May have solved another issue down the road.  Unfortunately, the original issue still resides